# How to create the effect like this page?

Tags: javascript, animation

Click "Reply by Email" of that page,

http://losangeles.kijiji.com/rooms-roommates/el-monte/room-for-rent-el-monte-california-91732/?ad=785656

Comment: Did you make any attempt whatsoever at finding out yourself? :)

Comment: @bzlm If you've never done stuff like this before it's not necessarily obvious where to start looking. Unobtrusive javascript makes searching for it difficult!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using jQuery you can simply use the show() method:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("#mydiv").show("slow");
});
```

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery the effect closer to that page is **slideDown**:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("#mydiv").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery. See [jQuery Effects/animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate).

Answer (score 0):

I believe MooTools is capable of doing this task. If not its not that hard to create that effect. Use setInterval to create an interval that repeats itself and resizes the box.

Answer (score 0):

Simply jQuery

With one line of code you can do this.

www.jquery.com